# CAO assignment, output won't work

Tags: c#

I have the main part of the program complete, I think, however at the end I need to output: the subject (subIn or sub1), the grade (gradeIn or grade1), and the points (pointsIn or points1).

I need to do this with a loop (point of the assignment) so when I try to run the program I can input the subject and grade but I can't figure out how to output all the information afterwards.

When the question "Do again?" comes up no matter if I put in "N" it will not output anything.

(Note, I know I have nothing actually in this code to output the information, but I have tried to put `Console.WriteLine` throughout the code with the necessary inputs but to no avail)

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace caoAssignment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Delcaring variables //
            string subIn, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5, sub6;
            string gradeIn, grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5, grade6;
            int pointsIn, points1, points2, points3, points4, points5, points6;
            int x;
            string doAgain = "";
            pointsIn = 0;

            // Getting the user to input necessary information. 2 peices needed. //

            do
            {
                x = 1;
                while (x <= 6)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a subject ");
                    subIn = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the grade you got in that subject (H1 - O8) ");
                    gradeIn = Console.ReadLine();

                    // Processing the grades in points //

                    if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "H1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 100;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "H2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 88;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "H3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 77;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "H4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 66;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "H5", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 56;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "H6", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 46;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "H7", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 37;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "H8", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 0;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "O1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 56;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "O2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 46;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "O3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 37;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "O4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 28;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "O5", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 20;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "O6", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 12;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "O7", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 0;
                    }

                    else if (string.Equals(gradeIn, "O8", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        pointsIn = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Input is wrong, please redo. ");
                    }

                    // Assigning each grade,subject and points depending on what X is //
                    if (x == 1)
                    {
                        sub1 = subIn;
                        grade1 = gradeIn;
                        points1 = pointsIn;

                    }

                    if (x == 2)
                    {
                        sub2 = subIn;
                        grade2 = gradeIn;
                        points2 = pointsIn;

                    }

                    if (x == 3)
                    {
                        sub3 = subIn;
                        grade3 = gradeIn;
                        points3 = pointsIn;

                    }

                    if (x == 4)
                    {
                        sub4 = subIn;
                        grade4 = gradeIn;
                        points4 = pointsIn;

                    }

                    if (x == 5)
                    {
                        sub5 = subIn;
                        grade5 = gradeIn;
                        points5 = pointsIn;

                    }

                    if (x == 6)
                    {
                        sub6 = subIn;
                        grade6 = gradeIn;
                        points6 = pointsIn;

                    }

                    x++;

                } // End of the while loop
                Console.WriteLine("Do again? (Y/N) ");
                doAgain = Console.ReadLine();

            } // End of the do loop //
            while (doAgain == "Y");


            // Command to keep the program open for the user //
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
`
```

Comment: You have to redo what you did with the input, but print values instead of making the user enter them. When reading the values, you looped until a specific count. Do that again after you are done with the input loop, but before you ask the user if he/she wants to "Do again".
Some hints to make it easier for you. Research putting the values in an array instead of several numbered variables. A `for` loop is simpler to handle than a while loop when you know the number of iterations up front.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are learning I don't want to ruin the fun. Here is pseudo code for what you are doing. I've added comments for the parts you want to take a closer look at.

```
do
{
    currentCount = 1;
    while (currentCount <= maxCount)
    {
        subject = ReadSubject();
        grade = ReadGrade();
        points = GetPointsFor(grade);

        if (IsValid(points)) //You currently have a bug here
        {
            StoreSubjectValues(currentCount, subject, grade, points);
            currentCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            PrintError(subject, grade);
        }
    }

    //This is what you want to add for the printout
    for (currentCount = 1; currentCount <= maxCount; currentCount++)
    {
        PrintSubjectValues(subjectValuesFor[currentCount]);
    }

    userWantsToContinue = AskUserToContinue();
} while (userWantsToContinue);
```

Regarding the loops, here is a handy guide:

- A `do` loop is good if you know you want to loop at least one time, but don't know how many until you have begun.
- A `while` loop is good if you don't know if you will loop at all and don't know when to end until you have begun.
- A `for` loop is good if you know how many times you will loop beforehand or if you are using a counter that should increment for every loop.

Look into using arrays when you know that you need to store many instances of the same type of value. In your case subjects, grades and points.  At later stages in your learning you would use Collections and classes/structures to store these, but get familiar with arrays before going down that road.

Good luck!